# ローカルサーバにある画像が取得できない

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

`ViewController`に`ImageView`が一つあり、ボタンを押すとローカルサーバにある画像をその`ImageView`表示させようとしているのですが、画像が表示されません。試しに`NSURL`で指定してあるURLにブラウザで飛ぶと、画像は表示されます。しかし`session.dataTaskWithURL`の`NSData`のログを取ってみたところ、ログに`<>`と表示されました。下記にコードを記します。どこが間違っているのでしょうか？どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
    @IBAction func tappedStartSession(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.downloadWithDataTask()
    }

    func downloadWithDataTask() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/dog.jpg")
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in

            if let d = data {

                let img = UIImage(data: d)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () in
                    self.imageView.image = img
                }
            }

            session.invalidateAndCancel()

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: シミュレータの話ですか、それとも実機でアプリを動かした場合の話ですか？シミュレータであれば、コードに問題はないはず。まるごとコピー＆ペーストして、`imageView`のイメージを入れ替えることができました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。上記のコードは実機で動かしました。しかし改めてシミュレータで動かしてみると画像は表示されました。コードには問題はなかったのですね。なぜ実機では表示されないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

実機からローカルサーバにアクセスする場合。iPhone/iPadは、Wi-Fiしかアクセス経路がありませんから、ローカルサーバがWi-Fi経由でアクセス可能な環境を用意しなければいけないでしょう。実機テストで、ローカルサーバとしても動いているMacと、実機がUSBでつながっているので、それでアクセスできてるという勘違いをなさっているのではありませんか？
ローカルサーバには「localhost」ドメインではアクセスできません。IPアドレスを置き換えればいいと思います。

[image: システム環境設定]

IPアドレスは、Macのシステム環境設定＞ネットワークで、調べられます。上図を参考にしてください。上図のIPアドレスであれば、

```
"http://localhost/dog.jpg"
```

は、

```
"http://10.0.1.13/dog.jpg"
```

となります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘通りMacと実機が繋がっているのでアクセスできると勘違いしていました。現在Wi-Fiに繋げれる環境がないので帰宅後に試してみたいと思います。

Comment: 帰宅後試したところ画像が表示されました。
誠にありがとうございました。